# Repeat a query over the parameter list

Tags: sql, dynamic

I would like to iterate the same query while using different parameter values from a predefined list.

Say, I have a table with two columns. The first columns contains customer name. The second column contains customer spending.

```
###CUSTOMER;     SPENDING###
customer1;       1000
customer2;       111
customer3;       100
customer1;       323
...
```

I know the complete list of customers: customerlist = {customer1, customer2, customer3}.

I would like to do something like:

```
Select sum(spending)
from mytable
where customer = @customerlist
```

The query should compute the sum of spending for each customer defined in the customer list. I have found some examples of sql procedures with stored parameters but not the case with one parameter of multiple values.

Thank you

P.S. This is just a hypothetical example to illustrate my question (I know it would be much more effective to use here a simple group by).

Comment: You should search for `rdbms string to rows` with `rdbms` is name of your rdbms, e.g. mssql. Then change `customer = @customerlist` to `customer IN (your_search_result);`

Comment: Different sql dialects handle this differently, but your question suggests SQL Server - TransactSQL.You can do it by passing the customer list as a table variable, and then change the `=` to `IN`

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested query like this

```
SELECT CustomerList.CustomerName Cust, isnull((SELECT SUM(Spending) CustSpending 
                FROM Customer 
                WHERE Customer.CustomerName = CustomerList.CustomerName),0) 
FROM CustomerList
```

Answer (score 0):

This would normally be done using `GROUP BY`:

```
Select customer, sum(spending)
from mytable
group by customer;
```

`GROUP BY` is a very fundamental part of SQL.  You should review your knowledge of SQL so you understand how to use it.